# All-Pairs Shortest Paths by Dijkstra

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

I searched for the Java implementation of all-pairs shortest paths by Dijkstra.
I found an algorithm for one source shortest path. I actually don't know Java, but I'm studying discrete mathematics, so maybe someone can help me. What I have to change to make it an all-pairs shortest path?

----------Edit -------
thanks templatetypedef again. i try it. now i think there is another little mistake in the code.

The input file(try.txt):

```
 0 2 68
 3 4 97
 0 3 8
```

This is the wrong output i get:

```
    From 3:
Shortest Path Cost to 3 is: 0.0
Shortest Path Cost to 2 is: Infinity
Shortest Path Cost to 0 is: Infinity
Shortest Path Cost to 4 is: 97.0

From 2:
Shortest Path Cost to 3 is: Infinity
Shortest Path Cost to 2 is: 0.0
Shortest Path Cost to 0 is: Infinity
Shortest Path Cost to 4 is: 97.0

From 0:
Shortest Path Cost to 3 is: 8.0
Shortest Path Cost to 2 is: 68.0
Shortest Path Cost to 0 is: 0.0
Shortest Path Cost to 4 is: 97.0

From 4:
Shortest Path Cost to 3 is: 8.0
Shortest Path Cost to 2 is: 68.0
Shortest Path Cost to 0 is: Infinity
Shortest Path Cost to 4 is: 0.0
```

The code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
    public final String name;
    public List<Edge1> adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;

    public Vertex(String argName) {
        name = argName;
        adjacencies = new ArrayList<Edge1>();
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge1 e) {
        adjacencies.add(e);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}

class Edge1{
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;

    public Edge1(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight) {
        target = argTarget;
        weight = argWeight;
    }
}


public class Dijkstra {

    public static void computePaths(Vertex source) {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each Edge exiting u

            for (Edge1 e : u.adjacencies) {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);
                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map<String, Vertex> vertexMap = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("try.txt"));
            String line;
            boolean inVertex = true;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {


                    //store the edges
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    String vFrom = parts[0];
                    String vTo = parts[1];
                    if(!vertexMap.containsKey(vFrom))
                    {
                        Vertex v= new Vertex(vFrom);
                        vertexMap.put(vFrom, v);
                    }
                    if(!vertexMap.containsKey(vTo))
                    {
                        Vertex v1= new Vertex(vTo);
                        vertexMap.put(vTo, v1);
                    }


                    double weight = Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
                    Vertex v = vertexMap.get(vFrom);
                    if (v != null) {
                        v.addEdge(new Edge1(vertexMap.get(vTo), weight));

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        finally{
            if(in!= null)
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
        }

        //get a list of all the vertices
        Collection<Vertex> vertices = vertexMap.values();

        //Vertex source = vertices.iterator().next();
        for(Vertex source:vertices){
        System.out.println("From " + source+":");
        computePaths(source);
        for (Vertex v : vertices) {
            System.out.println("Shortest Path Cost to " + v + " is: " + v.minDistance);
           // List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(v);
          //  System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        }System.out.println();
        source.minDistance=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        source.previous=null;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To compute all-pairs shortest paths with Dijkstra's algorithm, you would just rerun Dijkstra's algorithm multiple times, one for each possible starting node.  You should be able to easily adapt the above algorithm to get this logic to work by calling `computePaths(source)` for each possible source and remembering the shortest paths found at each point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user1951891- You need to clear all of the information computed by the previous iteration of Dijkstra's algorithm before running the algorithm again.  Otherwise, all of the previous information is going to interfere with the next run of the algorithm.

Comment: Hi sorry, but maybe you can tell me where should i initialize the information? i guess it's the variable V ?
(sorry i'm rude..i'm never learned java)

Comment: You need to reset the `minDistance` and `previous` fields in each `Vertex` object before running Dijkstra's one more time.  `minDistance` should get set to positive infinity again, and `previous` should probably get set to `null`.

Comment: Thanks again. i try it. it's imrpove some of the results. but there are still wrong distances. for example from 2 to 4 , should be INF too.

Comment: @templatetypedef I came across your site where i learnt set theory in the past but i cannot remember the url. Please can you share the url to help me understand computer science related Math.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, running Djikstra's multiple times to solve this problem will be `O(n^4)`.  [Floyd-Warhsall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) can solve it in `O(n^3)`.

Comment: With an appropriate priority queue, repeated Dijkstra's can be made to run in O(mn + n^2 log n), which is faster than Floyd-Warshall for sparse graphs.

Comment: Hi thanks. i know that Dijkstra not efficient for that. but i have to use this algorithem

Comment: Nope, even the worst implementation of Dijkstra running multiple times to do this thing only takes o(N^3), so ur statement is just wrong. We need to run Dijkstra for each starting node, not for each pair of start and terminal node.